# Loading a model, saved using Tensorflow 2.0, using Tensorflow 1.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am using the [transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) library by huggingface.

They have provided pre-trained models in Tensorflow 2.0 for a lot of architectures. I want to use these models for predictions on a TPU. Since the TPU API for Tensorflow 2.0 is still experimental, I want to do it in Tensorflow 1.x

Is there a way for me to convert a pre-trained model from Tensorflow 2.0 to Tensorflow 1.x, like it is possible to do vice versa or between frameworks?

The TPUE API for Tensorflow 2.0 is described here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training#tpustrategy and is still experimental and a proper tutorial for it has not been shared yet. Even the stub of code shared that is shared in this article was not working for me on Colab, hence I came up with the idea of converting the model to Tensorflow 1.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I can't guarantee this is the easiest way to run the conversion, I have run into the need to save and restore tensorflow variables as raw numpy arrays, and this could definitely help you with your conversion.

On the Tensorflow 2 side, make a dictionary of the Tensorflow variables and the names of those variables in the Tensorflow 1 graph, then make a dictionary with the names of the variables to the value they hold using variable.value().  You'll then probably need to serialize the name-value dictionary to a file, unless you can manage to load both versions of tensorflow simultaneously into the same program.

On the Tensorflow 1 side, use tf.trainable_variables() to fetch the list of variables to assign.  Get the name of the variable with variable.name, use the saved dictionary to fetch the value for that variable, and then use session.run(variable.assign(value)) to populate the parameters with the trained values.

A little bit cumbersome, admittedly, and it might not be hugely performant, but it shouldn't take more than two dozen lines of code to implement, at least!